# What are these balls in meshopyll cells? [Plant biology]

Tags: cell-biology, botany

Anybody knows what are these small balls? The picture was collected with a confocal fluorescence microscope. These balls have a green epifluorescence and they are in mesophyll cells of rice leaves.

[image]